# How can I play Colle System against Kingside Fianchetto?

Tags: opening, fianchetto, kingside, colle-system

I enjoy the Colle System as white, because it often leads to a strong kingside attack for white without exposing my own King to significant danger.

However, when my opponent castles behind a fianchetto on the kingside, I often struggle to understand how to attack it, as it significantly blunts the attack of my Bishop at `d3`, and advancing kingside pawns would likely open my own King up dangerously.

Can anyone point me to a good example of how to attack a fianchettoed king from the Colle system?

Comment: I think a `colle` tag would be appropriate, but I don't have the rep to add it.

Comment: Added that tag.

Comment: Have you looked into the Barry attack?  I'm not sure what move order you use, but that would be one way to proceed and try to force the game into a Pirc structure.

Answer (score 6):

If it conforms to your style of play, one possibility is to switch to a stonewall setup, which generally leads to a king-side pawn storm where the g6 pawn acts as a very convenient lever for opening up your opponent's king. It must be said, though, that an early king-side fianchetto followed by `...c5` to undermine the white center is probably one of the best and most aggressive ways to meet the Colle system, so if you're not prepared to vary your approach, you shouldn't be surprised if black achieves easy equality immediately out of the opening.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend against a Grunfeld  white play reversed Catalan lines    Against a KID either the Torre or... Or.. Play the French vs KIA lines as white!!! Pretty solid lines

Stonewall against delayed c5! Sure! Chances are your playing a Sicilian fanatic who plays that set up against everything... And who at the very least is gonna hate you for A) playing an opening he's not familiar with and that will not give him any of his normal attacking lines.

in the End U will have to learn solid line for the Dutch and a Anti Benoni line. Should be doable with the standard opening moves d4  Nf3 & e3 etc... won't be a Colle.. but ya can't have your cake and eat it to...

Just don't go chasing openings .. stick with the Colle & master it and then add to it where you think necessary.  Work on your middle and end game technique and study tactics...